# Toggle Slide-In Animation for Bootstrap 4 Desktop Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to expand and collapse the desktop version of the  Bootstrap 4 navigation with a simple toggle button.

So example would be a menu button to click and will minimise menu items into the left side of the screen.

[Menu]

[Menu] Link Link Link Link Link

Bootstrap defaults however don't provide desired result.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light main-nav">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item active nav-breaker">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Haircare</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-breaker">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book Appointment</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <a class="navbar-brand order-first order-md-0 mx-0" href="#">Shear Success</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that changing bootstrap's default navbar animations is not easy.However, I got you most of the way there: https://www.codeply.com/go/1VhJAMNHEO

1. your markup is not boostrap-compliant. fix your html so that you follow boostrap standards outlined [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler). See the section labeled "With a toggler on the left... "
2. remove the `navbar-expand-md` class from the nav to make the menu collapsed by default
3. override bootstrap's default styling to achieve the desired "slide in from the left" effect. this is much easier said than done. in particular the navbar adds a temporary class `.collapsing` that is easy to miss.
4. this is going to mess up responsive styling and will require more attention i.e. media queries.

honestly, if you want the navbar to do anything besides what's listed out on the documentation, I've found it easier to write most of my own styling and scripting from scratch, leveraging only the basic `.navbar` and `.navbar-nav` etc classes for styling